# Overwriting images in iPhoto app

Tags: ios, iphoto

I have a feature in my iOS application. The user has the option to save photo or video to the iPhoto app. When the user presses the 'Save' button, it saves the photo or video again. Is there a way to overwrite the existing file instead of saving it again.

```
     [self writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error)  {
                       //error handling
                       if (error!=nil) {
                           completionBlock(error);
                           return;
                       }

                       //add the asset to the custom photo album
                       [self addAssetURL: assetURL
                     withCompletionBlock:completionBlock];

                   }];
```

Any suggestion on this? Using checksum?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't, either you disable your Save button after click once or save to document directory and do checksum algorithm. Please check this answer [check image exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21656800/4016786)